# return object if his property matches all the items inside an array (ex ingredients for recipes)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I'm learning js and I was trying to filter recipes based on the ingredients I have inside an array but the check done with Array.every() seems to not work, what am I doing wrong?
Here's the code, thanks all!

```
const plates = [
  {
    name: "carbonara",
    ingredients: ["eggs", "milk", "pepper", "pasta", "cheese"],
    time: 30,
    difficulty: "easy",
  },
  {
    name: "oil_pepper",
    ingredients: ["oil", "pepper", "pasta", "garlic"],
    time: 20,
    difficulty: "medium",
  },
  {
    name: "tomato",
    ingredients: ["pasta", "tomato", "garlic", "onion"],
    time: "30",
    difficulty: "hard",
  },
];

const fridge = ["oil", "pepper", "pasta", "garlic"];


let filteredPlates = [];

const filter = () => {
  plates.forEach((element) =>
    fridge.forEach((element2) => {
      if (
        element.ingredients.every((element3) =>
          element3.includes(element2.toString())
        )
      ) {
        filteredPlates.push(element);
        return filteredPlates;
      }
    })
  );
};

filter();

console.log(filteredPlates);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over-complicating the problem. You just need to check for each plate, whether [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) ingredient in that plate's recipe is included in the fridge. You can use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for this purpose:

```js
const plates = [
  {
    name: "carbonara",
    ingredients: ["eggs", "milk", "pepper", "pasta", "cheese"],
    time: 30,
    difficulty: "easy",
  },
  {
    name: "oil_pepper",
    ingredients: ["oil", "pepper", "pasta", "garlic"],
    time: 20,
    difficulty: "medium",
  },
  {
    name: "tomato",
    ingredients: ["pasta", "tomato", "garlic", "onion"],
    time: "30",
    difficulty: "hard",
  },
];

const fridge = ["oil", "pepper", "pasta", "garlic"];

const filteredPlates = plates
  .filter(plt => plt.ingredients.every(ing => fridge.includes(ing)))

console.log(filteredPlates)
```